# GUI File Manager to show line count for all files

Tags: finder, command-line

Are there any GUI file managers like finder or any other file managers, which will show file row count?

I can see the row count from cli, using `wc` but I don't want to use cli all the time. GUI is quite handy to navigate the hierarchical folder. There are hundreds of files and I want to see row count in a seperate column.

I tried to find Finder extensions, which can do that but there are none.

Comment: What do you want shown for binary files?

Comment: Could be 0 or 1 or depends on how os is handling it. I am only looking for line count of text files. All other files for example, png/jpg can be ignored or shown "NA". @mmmmmm

Comment: In practice the cost will be too high as you would need to wc every file every tiome you looked at a directory in Finder. You might be btter off lookinmg for a document manager program

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the workflow/problem, in case there's another method of achieving what you want?

Comment: @mmmmmm I don't see any reason why cost will be high. In most the folders, a simple "wc *" returns response in milliseconds even if there are 100+ files. Can you provide an example of doc manager program which does this?

Comment: @benwiggy There are few data pipelines which read csv files from a folder and then output various folders containing csv files at each step. Line count of these files vary depending on the type of the file. So I need to scan these folders on a regular basis for row count first to detect any anamolies or sometimes just for summary purpose.

Comment: Sureky much easier to setup scripts to spot the anomalies. This would also be more reliable than a human looking

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not exactly what you're looking for, but this following **AppleScript** solution may help a little bit.

Paste this following code into a new **Script Editor.app** document.  When you run the code, it will first ask you to choose a folder to retrieve the line counts of all (**.txt, .log, .csv, .tsv** files) within that chosen folder (non-recursively).  It will then write the results to a file named **WC.txt** on your Desktop.

```
activate
set theFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder)

do shell script "cd " & theFolder & " ;find \"$PWD\" \\( -iname \"*.txt\" -o -iname \"*.log\" -o -iname \"*.csv\" -o -iname \"*.tsv\" \\) -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec wc -l {} \\; |sort -g > ~/Desktop/WC.txt"
```

Then, after a while, if you want to see if anything has changed, you can run the above code again.  However, this time send the results to a different file (~/Desktop/WC2.txt), for comparison.

To compare the two files you can simply run this command in **Terminal.app**

`diff ~/Desktop/WC.txt ~/Desktop/WC2.txt`